# compare multiple values in changing arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm making a basic javascript 'game', where objects (enemies) travel down from the top of the container, and a 'ship' shoots 'bullets' at the objects. There are many bullets and many enemies. I'm pushing every enemy object into an array, and the Y (top) value changes and is pushed into the array and updated with every change.

This is an interval that pushes the enemy down on the screen, and updates its _top value in the array.

```
enemyCoord = {
    _left : parseInt(enemy.style.left, 10),
    _top : enemyTop
}

enemyArray.push(enemyCoord);

var enemyInterval = setInterval(enemyMovement, 7 );

function enemyMovement(){
    enemyTop += 1;
    enemyArray[enemyCount]._top = enemyTop; // enemyCount is unique number given to each enemy object
    enemy.style.top = enemyTop + 'px';

    if (enemyTop >= document.getElementById('gc_1').offsetHeight -20 ) {
        clearInterval(enemyInterval);
        container.removeChild(enemy);
    }   
}
```

This is the bullet movement and where I attempt to make the values meet

```
function shoot(bullet, topValue) {

    var topValue = parseInt(topValue, 10);
    var bulletTop = topValue;
    var bulletInterval = setInterval(bulletMovement, 7);
    var arrayLength = enemyArray.length;


    function bulletMovement (){
        bulletTop = bulletTop - 1 ;
        bullet.style.top = bulletTop + 'px';
        if (bulletTop <= 20) {
            var container = document.getElementById('gc_1');
            container.removeChild(bullet);
            clearInterval(bulletInterval);
        }


        // This is the part I really need help with! Where the values meet
        for (var i=0;i<arrayLength;i++) {
            if (bulletTop === enemyArray[i]._top) {
                alert('we met :)');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I compare the parsed top style value of the bullets and the enemies? each bullet is checking against the array of enemy objects top value to see if it equals the bullets top value, but it doesn't work. How would I do this in a more efficient way?

Comment: What's your question? (Please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).)

Comment: Sorry Ed! I was a little tired when I posted that, I added the question to the bottom of the post.

Comment: @user3717403 what I don't understand is: if you only check for a bullet **top** position it does not mean that the bullet actually HIT the enemy ship. You're missing the X coordinate.

Comment: @user3717403 also `var container = document.getElementById('gc_1');` inside a `bulletMovement()` loop is not performant at all! Every single bullet on the screen - while moving they'll get over and over again a `#gc_1` element that actually you've could store initially at the top of your game script.

Comment: @user3717403 also `if (bulletTop === enemyArray[i]._top)` is probably not the right Y collision value. The enemy might have a HEIGHT indeed, so you need to add it to the calculation.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan True, my goal here is to match the Y value, as it changes every 7ms, but the X value stays the same. The bullets and enemies are on a straight vertical path, so if I found a matching (changing) Y value, I'd check it against the constant X values to see which one it hit. Thanks for the input Roko for insight, I'll store the #gc_1 at the top of the document. Also I'll add element height in after I can successfully compare values.